# Passing data to .call in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This experiment is based on the [Health & Wealth of Nations](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/) example. I'm trying to have a tooltip-style label show up and float above each of the dots when the mouse hovers over them. Each data element has a property called "name" that I'd like to display in the tooltip. For the sake of brevity I omitted most of the irrelevant code.

```
// Create all the dots, one for each data point.
var dot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
  .selectAll(".dot")
    .data(myData)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .call(position)
    .call(enableInteraction)
    .sort(order);

// Create a tooltip element.
var tooltip = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "tooltip");

// Assign each of the dots the various mouse events.
function enableInteraction(dot) {
  dot.on("mouseover", mouseover)
     .on("mouseout", mouseout)
     .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mouseover() {
    tooltip.text(???); // How do I get the name into here?
  }

  function mouseout() {
    tooltip.text("");
  }

  function mousemove() {
    var cursor = d3.mouse(this);
    tooltip.attr("x", cursor[0] + 5)
           .attr("y", cursor[1] + 5);
  }
}
```

I tried using a function to retrieve the name and pass it into enableInteraction() as follows:

```
.call(enableInteraction, function(d) { return d.name; } )
```

but the function object is being passed instead of its return value.

So how do I get each data element's name to display in the tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a currying technique to get that info into your *mouseover* event handler.  I'm unsure of the syntax for getting the name, but this is the idea:

```
// this function returns a function
function moveoverHandler(dot) {
    return function mouseover() {

        // I'm not sure if this is how you get the "name" property from the "dot" object 
        // Please update this as needed
        var name = dot.data("name");  

        tooltip.text(name);  
    }
}
```

Then wire up the handler like this:

```
dot.on("mouseover", mouseover(dot));
```